# Counter keeps resetting in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, css-counter

I am trying to write an electronic book, and I'm having problems with counters for managing chapters/sections/subsections.

```css
body {
  counter-reset: chapter;
  counter-reset: section;
  counter-reset: subsection;
}

h1.chapter::before {
  counter-reset: section;
  counter-reset: subsection;
  counter-increment: chapter;
  content: "Chapter " counter(chapter) ": ";
}

h2.section::before {
  counter-reset: subsection;
  counter-increment: section;
  content: "Section " counter(chapter) "." counter(section) ": ";
}

h3.subsection::before {
  counter-increment: subsection;
  content: "Subsection " counter(chapter) "." counter(section) "." counter(subsection) ": ";
}
```

```html
<h1 class="chapter"> The first chapter</h1>
<h2 class="section"> The first section </h2>
<h2 class="section"> The second section </h2>
<h3 class="subsection"> The first subsection </h3>
<h3 class="subsection"> The second subsection </h3>
<h1 class="chapter"> The second chapter</h1>
<h2 class="section"> The second chapter's first section</h2>
<h3 class="subsection"> The second chapter's first subsection </h3>
```

and this is what shows up:

[image]

So I have no idea why the `chapter` and `section` just don't stick while `subsection' doesn't reset...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move the reset from the pseudo element. Also, you can reformat the `counter-reset` on the body to include all of them in one statement.

```css
body {
  counter-reset: chapter section subsection;
}

h1.chapter::before {
  counter-increment: chapter;
  content: "Chapter " counter(chapter) ": ";
}

h1.chapter {
  counter-reset: section;
}

h2.section::before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: "Section " counter(chapter) "." counter(section) ": ";
}

h2.section {
  counter-reset: subsection;
}

h3.subsection::before {
  counter-increment: subsection;
  content: "Subsection " counter(chapter) "." counter(section) "." counter(subsection) ": ";
}
```

```html
<h1 class="chapter"> The first chapter</h1>
<h2 class="section"> The first section </h2>
<h2 class="section"> The second section </h2>
<h3 class="subsection"> The first subsection </h3>
<h3 class="subsection"> The second subsection </h3>
<h1 class="chapter"> The second chapter</h1>
<h2 class="section"> The second chapter's first section</h2>
<h3 class="subsection"> The second chapter's first subsection </h3>
```

Here is a fiddle to play with:
https://jsfiddle.net/muc0q9aw/

Comment: Thanks. I guess I need to learn more about 'pseudo-elements' now ;)

Comment: They're fun! The thing to keep in mind is the `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements are like blank spaces that don't appear in the DOM but are attached to the element you add them to - so when you had the `counter-reset` on the `::before` pseudo, it had no connection to the following elements (`h2`, `h3` in your case).  That's really a layman's basic explanation :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use **only** one reset per element or you will simply override the first ones with the last one like with any properties.

[image]

You should also pay attention to where you need to use `counter-reset`:

> Counters are "self-nesting", in the sense that resetting a counter in a descendant element or pseudo-element automatically **creates a new instance of the counter.**

Then

> The scope of a counter starts at the first element in the document **that has a 'counter-reset'** for that counter and includes the **element's descendants and its following siblings with their descendants** <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#counters)</sup>

Considering this you shouldn't reset the counter inside a pseudo-element but the element itself so that the sibling elements will have the good value.

```css
body {
  counter-reset: chapter section subsection;
}
h1.chapter {
  counter-reset: section subsection;
}
h1.chapter::before {
  counter-increment: chapter;
  content: "Chapter " counter(chapter) ": ";
}

h2.section {
  counter-reset: subsection;
}
h2.section::before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: "Section " counter(chapter) "." counter(section) ": ";
}

h3.subsection::before {
  counter-increment: subsection;
  content: "Subsection " counter(chapter) "." counter(section) "." counter(subsection) ": ";
}
```

```html
<h1 class="chapter"> The first chapter</h1>
<h2 class="section"> The first section </h2>
<h2 class="section"> The second section </h2>
<h3 class="subsection"> The first subsection </h3>
<h3 class="subsection"> The second subsection </h3>
<h1 class="chapter"> The second chapter</h1>
<h2 class="section"> The second chapter's first section</h2>
<h3 class="subsection"> The second chapter's first subsection </h3>
```

You can also simplify your code like below:

```css
body {
  counter-reset: chapter; /*we reset the chapter once*/
}
h1.chapter {
  counter-reset: section; /*we reset the section each chapter*/
}
h1.chapter::before {
  counter-increment: chapter;
  content: "Chapter " counter(chapter) ": ";
}

h2.section {
  counter-reset: subsection; /*we reset the subsection each section*/
}
h2.section::before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: "Section " counter(chapter) "." counter(section) ": ";
}

h3.subsection::before {
  counter-increment: subsection;
  content: "Subsection " counter(chapter) "." counter(section) "." counter(subsection) ": ";
}
```

```html
<h1 class="chapter"> The first chapter</h1>
<h2 class="section"> The first section </h2>
<h2 class="section"> The second section </h2>
<h3 class="subsection"> The first subsection </h3>
<h3 class="subsection"> The second subsection </h3>
<h1 class="chapter"> The second chapter</h1>
<h2 class="section"> The second chapter's first section</h2>
<h3 class="subsection"> The second chapter's first subsection </h3>
```

Comment: How did I not see your answer when I was posting mine?! Oh well, take an upvote.

Comment: @disinfor I hit the submit too fast, so I had to delete for a short moment to edit then undelete ;)