# CSS auto numbering without nested section

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve CSS autonumbering when the content is not "really" nested. 
My situation comes from a PDF generation, which involves several html pages all merged together (one page after the other), therefore the content is not really nested, each page will be appended in a new div.

The situation I am facing looks similar to the following example  (also created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/balvarez/kawmvhzx/1/))

```css
body {
  counter-reset: h1 h2 h3;
}

h1,
h2,
h3 {
  color: green;
}

h1::before,
h2::before,
h3::before {
  color: black;
}

h3::before {
  color: red;
}

h1 {
  counter-reset: h2;
}

h2 {
  counter-reset: h3;
}

h1::before {
  counter-increment: h1;
  content: counter(h1)" ";
}

h2::before {
  counter-increment: h2;
  content: counter(h1) "." counter(h2) " ";
}

h3::before {
  counter-increment: h3;
  content: counter(h1) "." counter(h2) "." counter(h3) " ";
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <h1>1</h1>
    <h2>1.1</h2>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>1.1.1</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>1.2</h2>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>1.2.1</h3>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You can't...that's not the way CSS counters work. You will need JS.

Comment: if it's about nested hx, :first-of-type could be usefull for the reset part, https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XQVgjM seems okay with your bits of code , but will it do in real ?

Comment: JS is actually not possible in this case because of the PDF generation, there are certain restrictions I cannot jump and having a JS for the entire document is not an option, that is why I wanted to go for the CSS solution. So, without nesting...not possible?

Comment: nested or not doesn't seem to be a trouble,  counter will follow the tree but won't mind it . a reset can be made anywhere. Your code seems to show a bug, where a 0 shows up. counter here is lost, not really reset . Reset should also be done on ::before, since counter-increment is done from there (Hint, to avoid bug/confusion and keep same selector wheight)  Was https://jsfiddle.net/nxL29rfb/ not fiting your needs / DOM ?

Comment: @G-Cyr I am not able to understand why your code is working fine :/ ... it's seems to fix the OP issue but it's shouldn't as the main issue is that the element aren't siblings so the scope of the counter isn't the same of all (like I explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55070713/8620333)

Comment: @TemaniAfif it looks like working because i used first-of-type and hx tags are nested. beside to avoid the bug, i also used the ::before pseudo-element because it is used to increment the counter to stay coherent with the selectors. If element are not nested , then the first-of-type is not needed, it is the classic way to use counter. ;) It only seems to work, because the way div are spread into div here, not sure it reflects the real case

Comment: The provided solution doesnt work because it will only work for really small content. As I mentioned, I am creating a dynamically generated PDFs, with over 70 pages each, so `:first-of-type` is not really a solution, see my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/balvarez/kawmvhzx/1/)