# CSS counter-reset problem: Intended behavior or bug?

Tags: css, css-counter

I have **two counters** on the  level that run through the whole page; one for figures and one for tables. The page is divided into several div.

When both counters are active, the counters are **reset at a new div**. When only one counter is active, it counts correctly through the end of the page.

Is that intended behavior or simply a bug? I can put one counter reset on the html level and it will work properly, but what if I had even more counters?

EDIT:
1) Why would the counter reset at the first div it encounters and not at the end of the body tag? 
2) To clarify, I don't want achieve a nested counter hierarchy. I want both counters to run in parallel; one covering figures, the other tables. I guess I could add empty div brackets to place the various counters on. Not the cleanest solution but it should work.

```css
body {
  counter-reset: figure-counter;
  /*  counter-reset: table-counter;  */
  /*  works correctly with table-counter disabled.  */
}

figure.figure {
  counter-increment: figure-counter;
}

figure.figure figcaption b::before {
  content: "Figure " counter(figure-counter) ": ";
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
  <figure class="figure">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x30">
    <figcaption><b>Lorem ipsum dolor.</b> Sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="figure">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x30">
    <figcaption><b>Lorem ipsum dolor.</b> Sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
<div>
  <figure class="figure">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x30">
    <figcaption><b>Lorem ipsum dolor.</b> Sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
  <figure class="figure">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x30">
    <figcaption><b>Lorem ipsum dolor.</b> Sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: only one counter-reset should be used and all the counters inside: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55070713/8620333

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the quick response! Still the answer provided is somehow different: I don't want a nested counter to restart at the chapter level. Both counters should run through the whole article in parallel. You say only only one counter can be applied per level. This seems as some sort of shortcoming. Is there a workaround besides adding additional empty parent divs to place the counter-reset on?

Comment: you don't need to nest anything or add a parent element, check the answer I linked to understand how to consider multiple counter on the same element. I said only one *counter-reset* not only one counter

Comment: Thanks. You pointed me into the right direction. I solved it by adding reset classes for each counter on the body element.