# CSS counters doesn't work in subitems inside of div

Tags: html, css, css-counter

I'm trying to use the CSS counter to create Chapter numbers.
As you can see in the example below, it's working properly if I deal with classes inside a container, but doesn't work when I try to use it in subitems inside div. Any idea how to correct this behavior ? (I need to use this kind of structure)

```css
.itemsContainer {
  counter-reset: section;
}

.t1 {
  counter-reset: subsection;
}

.t1:before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counter(section) ". ";
}

.t2:before {
  counter-increment: subsection;
  content: counter(section) "."counter(subsection) " ";
}
```

```html
<h3>Direct access to class</h3>
<div class="itemsContainer">
  <p class="t1"></p>
  <p class="t2"></p>
  <p class="t2"></p>
</div>

<h3>Inside div</h3>
<div class="itemsContainer">
  <div class="item">
    <p class="t1"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p class="t2"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p class="t2"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: counter has a scope, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55070713/8620333

Answer (score 2):

Error here come from the rule:

```css
.itemsContainer {
  counter-reset: section;
}
```

So each time that you have an `.itemsContainer` element the counter `section` is going to be reset.

To avoid this just say that only the **first** `.itemsContainer` element reset the counter:

```css
.itemsContainer:nth-of-type(1) {
  counter-reset: section;
}
```

For the "Inside div" part you will need to increment the `subsection` using `.item` and not `.item .t2`. Don't forget that the first element don't have to increment the counter. In css you can use the `:not()` property for that:

```css
.item:not(:first-child) {
  counter-increment: subsection;
}
```

Please check the demo:

```css
.itemsContainer:nth-of-type(1) {
  counter-reset: section;
}

.itemsContainer .t1 {
  counter-reset: subsection;
}

.t1::before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counter(section) ". ";
}

.item:not(:first-child) {
  counter-increment: subsection;
}

.itemsContainer>.t2::before {
  counter-increment: subsection;
  content: counter(section) "."counter(subsection) " ";
}

.itemsContainer>.item>.t2::before {
  content: counter(section) "."counter(subsection) " ";
}
```

```html
<h3>Direct access to class</h3>
<div class="itemsContainer">
  <p class="t1"></p>
  <p class="t2"></p>
  <p class="t2"></p>
</div>

<h3>Inside div</h3>
<div class="itemsContainer">
  <div class="item">
    <p class="t1"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p class="t2"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p class="t2"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

For further details just check the W3C documentation: https://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_counters.asp

Comment: Numbers are not resetting after "Inside div", isn't that a weird behavior ?

Comment: @TmZn What do you mean by that ?